# OpenTelemetry Metrics for Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus, metrics

I have used OTEL for quakrus for tracing. But is there also metrics? like can I stream SmallRyeMetrics to OTEL?

Answer (score 3):

Currently the recommended way to produce metrics on Quarkus is with Micrometer. Quarkus is moving away from MicroProfile Metrics and it's implementation with SmallRye Metrics

With Micrometer on Quarkus you can output the results in the standard OTLP (OpenTelemetry) format with the [OTLP exporter](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-micrometer-registry/tree/main/micrometer-registry-otlp).
Please also check the Guide: https://quarkus.io/guides/micrometer